# Two column table to pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I am new to sql pivot and trying to convert two column table in to pivot

```
DECLARE @From date='1/1/2010',
        @To date ='1/1/2015'


Declare @TempDate datetime
Declare @xDate datetime
Set @xDate = @From 


Create Table #Dates(SYear int,StartDate datetime)

While (@xDate <= @To)
    Begin
        Set @TempDate = Convert(Datetime,Str(Month(@xDate)) + '/1/' + STR(Year(@xDate)))
        Insert Into #Dates values (Year(@TempDate),@TempDate)
        set @xDate =  DATEADD(YEAR, 1, @xDate)
    End     

---Getting these error message in pivot
```

*The column name "StartDate" specified in the PIVOT operator conflicts with the existing column name in the PIVOT argument.*

*The column name "SYear" specified in the PIVOT operator conflicts with the existing column name in the PIVOT argument.*

```
    Select SYear MyYear,StartDate FromDate
   From (
      Select SYear,StartDate
      From #Dates
     ) D
    Pivot(
        Max(SYear)
        For StartDate in (FromDate)
    )piv;
```

I am trying to generate something like below

[image]

Comment: Your sample would mean more if you showed us what is supposed to go in the field that is at the intersection of a year and a date.

Comment: Your pivot syntax is just wrong.  Look at the documentation http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx.  The `in` should contain a list of values.  You seem to want a dynamic pivot.  I would suggest you google for that.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I tried with the instruction, but now have a different error "Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime"

Comment: On a greater scale, what are you trying to do? Is there more to just the years and dates, like some data that needs to be aggregated? Or are you learning how PIVOT works? Or are you just trying to generate an empty grid using some kind of a configuration table? For your source table is not really the kind that PIVOT is typically used with.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need to use `pivot` you can use `dynamic` `SQL` and `cursor` see example below:

```
DECLARE @From date='1/1/2010',
        @To date ='1/1/2015'


Declare @TempDate datetime
Declare @xDate datetime
Set @xDate = @From 


Create Table #Dates(SYear int,StartDate datetime)

While (@xDate <= @To)
    Begin
        Set @TempDate = Convert(Datetime,Str(Month(@xDate)) + '/1/' + STR(Year(@xDate)))
        Insert Into #Dates values (Year(@TempDate),@TempDate)
        set @xDate =  DATEADD(YEAR, 1, @xDate)
    End    


---dynamic sql and cursor

DECLARE @increment int
SET @increment = 0;
DECLARE @sqlCommand nvarchar(1000)
DECLARE @datestring nvarchar(1000)
DECLARE @StartDate AS datetime;
DECLARE KURSOR_DY CURSOR FOR
        SELECT StartDate FROM #Dates GROUP BY StartDate;        
OPEN KURSOR_DY; 
FETCH NEXT FROM KURSOR_DY INTO @StartDate;  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN   
    IF (@increment) = 0 
    BEGIN
        SET @datestring = '''' + '''' + ' as ['+convert(nvarchar(max), @StartDate, 103)+']'
    END
    IF (@increment) > 1
    BEGIN
        PRINT @datestring
        SET @datestring = @datestring + ', ''' + '''' + ' as ['+convert(nvarchar(max), @StartDate, 103)+']';
    END 
    FETCH NEXT FROM KURSOR_DY INTO @StartDate;  
    SET @increment = @increment + 1
END
CLOSE KURSOR_DY;    
DEALLOCATE KURSOR_DY;
SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT SYear as [ ], '+ @datestring +
        ' FROM (select SYear, StartDate from #Dates) as A GROUP BY SYear';
EXEC(@sqlCommand)

drop table #Dates
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I thought Pivot is more suitable, however this works!!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Select SYear,StartDate
From #Dates
Pivot (
 Max(SYear)
 For #Dates in (StartDate,SYear)
 ) as pivottable;
```